# Normal Random Variable With Mean and Variance

Tags: normal-distribution, means, variance

I can't figure out at all how to do this problem. Any notes I have found on the topic have been really vague. Any help would be appreciated!

> Let X be a normal random variable with mean 12 and variance 4.
>   Find
>   approximations to the following:
>   (a) the value of a such that P(X > a) = 0.10.
>   (b) the value of b such that P(X < b) = 0.05.
>   (c) the value of c such that P(−c < X − 12 < c) = 0.95.
>   (d) the value of d such that P(12 − d < X < 12 + d) = 0.3

Comment: Are you familiar with standard normal tables and how to standardize a normal random variable?

Comment: a very basic familiarity.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at the standard normal table (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table).

$X$ is a normal random variable with mean $12$ and variance $2^2$, meaning that

$$Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} = \frac{X-12}{2}$$

is a normal random variable with mean $0$ and variance $1$. The probabilities you are interested in can then be found in tables such the ones above.

Comment: $Z=\frac{X-12}{4}$ has variance $\frac14$.

Comment: That's correct, thank you !

Comment: Im still unsure how to get any of the probabilities with this though...

Comment: You look for the number $a$ such that $P(X>a)=10\%$, that is to say $P(2Z+12 > a) = 10\%$, or $P(Z > (a-12)/2) = 10\%$. Using the standard table, it is easy to find $(a-12)/2$ and therefore $a$